# How could I JSON.parse nested object inside array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm trying to pass this structure on a PHP/Ajax response:

```
{"asn":"167", "jte":"[[1381547700000,0.0], [1381548600000,0.0]]", "visitas":"[{x:1380596400000,text:'HELLO WORLD.',title:'X'}]"}
```

But JSON.parse returns an error.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
```

Without the "visitas" object everything runs fine. Is it possible to "nest" as this?

UPDATE:

Ajax Part:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'post', 
                    url: 'cxxx.php',
                    data: { asn: asn }, 
                    success: function(p){
                        p = JSON.parse(p);

                        jusante=JSON.parse(p.jusante);
                        montante=JSON.parse(p.montante);
                        vazao=JSON.parse(p.vazao);
                        minima=JSON.parse(p.minima);
                        fator=JSON.parse(p.fator);
                        visitas=JSON.parse(p.visitas)
```

and PHP part:

```
    $v="[";
while(odbc_fetch_row($res)){
    $datavisita = odbc_result($res, "DATA_VISITA");
    $descricaovisita = odbc_result($res, "DESCRICAO_VISITA");
    $login = odbc_result($res, "LOGIN");
    $descricaomotivo = odbc_result($res, "DESCRICAO_MOTIVO");
    $id_motivo=odbc_result($res, "ID_MOTIVO");

    $datavisita=date("U", strtotime($datavisita))*1000;
    $descricaovisita=preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $descricaovisita);

    $v.="{x:$datavisita,text:'$descricaovisita',title:'$id_motivo'}, ";
}
$v=rtrim($v,", ")."]";


echo "{\"asn\": \"$asn\", \"description\": \"$description\", \"jusante\": \"$o\", \"montante\": \"$m\", \"vazao\": \"$f\", \"minima\": \"$mn\", \"fator\": \"$fp\", \"visitas\": \"$v\" }";
```

Comment: This appears to be valid JSON syntax.  Do you have a jsfiddle showing this error?

Comment: can we see the code encoding this and the code trying to parse it?

Comment: @DanEsparza debugging using FF firebug.

Comment: @JanDvorak added serialization code.

Comment: So from what it seems, you are trying to send all that data from PHP to Javascript. Correct? or is it from JS to PHP???

Comment: I don't json_encode getting called like I would expect, since it's PHP ... see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @DiegoCamacho yes. JS calls PHP wich sends this object as resonse.

Comment: oh ok. Why send the PHP response like that? you need to encode it first. you need to use json_encode

Comment: Im trying to come up with a better output to your PHP hold on

Comment: Were you able to get an answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Json you are using is valid, I checked it on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), so your problem might be with serialization, just make sure your "visitas" object is serialized correctly because the problem might be happening because it's the only member with an object value inside

Comment: In fact, I was serializing the php output as string and it works fine for non texts and simple arrays (or array of arrays), but, when it comes to objects all this fails. The solution is to properly use the php array object to store all data and then output it using json_encode. Also note that strings must be utf8 enconded before json send. thx all.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the `visitas` array:

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"asn": "167","jte": "[[1381547700000,0.0], [1381548600000,0.0]]", "visitas": [{"x": "1380596400000", "text":"HELLOWORLD.","title":"X"}]}');
```

Comment: Really? Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/2wzw7/ No errors for me (looking in Chrome).

Comment: strange... se code above. For me (on FF firebug) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
[Parar neste erro]  

visitas=JSON.parse(p.visitas);

Comment: Funny, worked for me in FF too... FF 24.0. Oh well, I guess YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

While the outermost JSON object looks fine, there might be a problem with the nested one!

If you are trying to parse the nested JSON element "visitas" you might have a problem in the fact that your property names (e.g. x, text and title) are not enclosed in quotation marks ("). This is of course a bit tricky since you are trying to include the visitas element as a string.

A solution might be to include the visitas element as a proper JSON element instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes. I imagine you are surrounding the above in single quotes when you pass it to JSON.parse.

The below works.

```
JSON.parse('{"asn":"167", "jte":"[[1381547700000,0.0], [1381548600000,0.0]]", "visitas":"[{x:1380596400000,text:\'HELLO WORLD.\',title:\'X\'}]"}');
```

Note the slashes before the single quotes inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
var jsondata = {
                    "asn": "167",
                    "jte": "[[1381547700000,0.0], [1381548600000,0.0]]",
                    "visitas": "[{x:1380596400000,text:'HELLO WORLD.',title:'X'}]"
                };

jsondata = JSON.stringify(jsondata);
```

then send it to php

```
var postdata = { data : jsondata};
var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"test";


$.post(url, postdata, function(result){

    console.log(result);

});
```

Comment: here's the answer ` [data] => {"asn":"167","jte":"[[1381547700000,0.0], [1381548600000,0.0]]","visitas":"[{x:1380596400000,text:'HELLO WORLD.',title:'X'}]"}`

Answer (score 0):

sice your php result is echoed the wrong way you should fix that first. Create arrays so that you can easily use the JSON_ENCODE function like so:

```
$array = array(
            "asn" => "test_asn",
            "description" => "description_test",
            "jusante" => "jusante_test",
            "montante" => "montante_test",
            "vazao" => "vazao_test",
            "minima" => "minima_test",
            "fator" => "fator_test",
            "visitas" => "visitas_test"
            );
 $json = json_encode($array);
 echo $json;
```